# ready codes for calculating integrals, FFT, MLE, drawing graphs, simulate trajectories

Tags: programming, mle

I'm looking for ready-made codes (R, Python or Matlab) for calculating integrals, simulate trajectories of stochastic processes (like CGMY), Fast Fourier Transform, maximum likelihood estimation and for drawing graphs like in the picture where prices are marked with a circle and a plus sign. I'm not a programmer myself so I can't write the code. Will I find them somewhere? Which sites/blogs do you reccomend where I could find ready codes?[image]

Answer (score 2):

- There is not one package that does of all this, but you can look at the QuantLib bindings for R and Python for the Quant stuff.
- All three languages have excellent plotting libraries.
- Information about this can be found all over the internet, i.e. on Google, GitHub and here. I don't believe there can be one blog that does a deep dive in all of these topics and has ready made code for you to download.